# InvalidArgumentException when saving a view

Tags: views, 8

I have a view named News containing Aggregated RSS feeds.  I noticed duplicate articles were appearing.  First I tried to enable Query Settings > DISTINCT, but the duplicates still remained so I disabled DISTINCT. I enabled Use aggregation > YES and added "COUNT(DISTINCT Aggregator feed item: Title) (= 1)" to Filter which seems to do the trick in the preview, however when I try to save the page it results in an error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> InvalidArgumentException: The configuration property display.default.display_options.filters.title.value.value doesn't exist. in `Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get()` (line 74 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement.php).

Is this something I did wrong, or just a bug in Drupal? How should I proceed?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I suggest you create a core issue, with exact steps to reproduce.

Comment: Did you solved it?